# PayPal IPN - What is Sent to ipn.php?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I've gotten a subscription module setup and I am unsure of what PayPal sends back to my ipn.php file.

Picture this:

My website -> PayPal Payments(for subscription) -> Payment Success -> Process -> ipn.php

What does ipn.php receive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal will send back the transaction data such as transaction ID, amount, fees amount to your IPN listener depending on the transaction type.

Here's a list of all the variable that IPN might be sending to you. 
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/